# ENV_VAR=${sh_var} set in sh script

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, sh, uwsgi

Let me preface by saying I *think* this is my problem. I'm not 100% sure. I'm hoping someone can tell me if I'm correct here...

I have a script I'm writing to install my go-to server stack from source in userland. Part of this script involves installing uWSGI with the PHP plugin. The part of the script in question is:

```
UWSGICONFIG_PHPDIR=${HOME}/php54 UWSGI_EMBED_PLUGINS=${uwsgiplugins} python2.7 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

`UWSGICONFIG_PHPDIR` is my custom-compiled PHP installation and `UWSGI_EMBED_PLUGINS` is the env variable to compile uWSGI with plugins embedded in the binary. I have this set via `uwsgiplugins=php` at the beginning of the script.

When I run the script the PHP plugin is not compiled into the uWSGI binary. The best I can figure is that this is an issue with trying to pass a script variable to an env variable. If, after I run the script, I manually enter `UWSGICONFIG_PHPDIR=${HOME}/php54 UWSGI_EMBED_PLUGINS=php python2.7 uwsgiconfig.py --build` into the command line then the uWSGI binary compiles properly with the embedded PHP plugin.

Am I doing something wrong in trying to pass a variable from the sh script to an env variable on the command line? Should I be setting these variables via a different method?

Comment: put an `echo uwsgiplugins=$uwsgiplugins` just before the problem command in the script and see if the variable is actually set

Comment: You might show more of the script - do you source a config file that sets this uwsgiplugins variable?  Your script might benefit from sourcing a config file that has all these environment variables assigned.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was running `make` after the build script, building it twice. The second time without the config variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `env` command and do not forge to quote your variables:

```
 env UWSGICONFIG_PHPDIR="${HOME}/php54" UWSGI_EMBED_PLUGINS="${uwsgiplugins}" python2.7 uwsgiconfig.py --build
```